# nginx SSL fail error:0909006C

Tags: nginx, ssl, centos8

I'm configuring a SSL certificate from GoDaddy and have followed all their instructions in the page: https://br.godaddy.com/help/nginx-on-centos-7-install-a-certificate-27192?lc=en-US

I am running o CentOS8

I am still getting the following error:

```
SSL: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
```

I configured my nginx server as

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name 185.224.81.18;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/vegazbet.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/generated-private-key.txt;

    include ssl.conf;

    include       proxy_params;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5010;
    }

    location /static {
        root /home/useradmin/vegazbet/web/app;
    }

    location /socket.io {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5010/socket.io;
    }
}

SSL.CONF
ssl_protocols               TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ecdh_curve              secp384r1;
ssl_ciphers                 "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 OLD_TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 OLD_TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256";
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
ssl_session_timeout         10m;
ssl_session_cache           shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_tickets         off;
ssl_stapling                on;
ssl_stapling_verify         on;

PROXY_PARAMS
proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host    $host;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port    $server_port;
```

Does anyone have any ideia what that error means?

I've looked through lots of forum posts here and found no one with the exact same error...

Comment: Where exactly did you obtain the private key and certificate? It seems the files are somehow corrupted.

Comment: I downloaded them from godaddy. They generated the private key and the crt file (crt file was already concatenated with Intermediate Certificate Chain)

Comment: Then I sftp d them to my server

Comment: The name `generated-private-key.txt` is suspicious.

Comment: How can I check if it is correct, when i open it it looks like a regular private key. starts qith -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----

Comment: Do `od -c generated-private-key.txt` and **make sure it starts with _exactly_ the characters** `- - - - - B E G I N (sp) P R I V A` then `T E (sp) K E Y - - - - - \n` (where I use (sp) to indicate a blank space) **with nothing else** before the first hyphen, although you _may_ have `\r` before the `\n`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, turns out the file was formatted as UTF eith BOM, removing the bom made it work